# Issue in initialization of constructor from derived class

Tags: c++

In a.hpp file

```
class top
{
public:
 class Base
  {  
    int x; 
    int y;
  public:
    Base(int p, int q) : x(p), y(q) {}
  };
  class Derived : public Base
  {
    public:
    Derived():Base ( NULL, NULL ); // error
  };
};
```

I have a base class and a derived class. While calling the constructor of derived class I want to pass the base class and initialize it with some parameters. What wrong am I doing here?

Comment: `Derived():Base ( 0, 0 ) {}` As written, the `Derived` constructor is missing the body; and `NULL` is for pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>  // error
> ```
>
> What wrong am I doing here?

When you get an error, the first step is to read the error message.

You are doing these wrong:

- You initialise a integers with `NULL`. `NULL` is only for pointers. Not all null pointer constants are integer literals, so this may or might not be ill-formed on all language implementations. Furthermore, `NULL` shouldn't be used at all since all its use cases have been superseded by `nullptr`.
- You forgot to provide a body for the constructor. Function body must be a block statement. It may not be a null statement i.e. it may not be just `;`.
- You forgot semicolon after your class definition.